# replacing part of the string using php

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I have problem replacing part of the string.

```
$val='Today';

$string ='TodayRainy';

str_replace($val, '',$string);
```

length of `$val` varies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str_replace()` returns the new string. It does not change it in place. This means you have the assign the results to a variable:

```
$new_string = str_replace($val, '',$string);
```